How to have a 16:9 fullscreen application inside an ultrawide monitor?
I have a 32:9 monitor at the moment, but I want to run fullscreen applications at 16:9, for games, youtube, etc. while having the rest of the monitor also be used. I have already tried displayfusion and powertoys to split the screen up, however it doesn't work with fullscreen applications. Any way I can do this? I have a Oddysey Neo G9 57". I have a temporary solution, setting my monitors resolution to 3840x2160, which works, but then I have half my monitor unused.

Many fullscreen applications also support borderless windowed mode. Maybe that’s for you?

borderless windowed mode would still add black bars. If you go that route, just use windowed mode, and set a slightly smaller resolution. That's what I do too. My monitor is 3440x1440, I usually game at say. 1920x1200 or similar, depending on what resoltions the game offers and fits.

An alternative option would be to see if your monitor has multiple inputs. If it has, say 2 DP inputs, then each input is likely going to be for the left and right half of the display. If both cables are connected to the same GPU, windows should treat it as 2 monitors with half its horizontal resolution. You may need to change the monitor's mode to PIP or something...

What doesn't work
There's no easy way to solve this completely and for all applications via software. It's a feature which has been requested 10 years ago on the DisplayFusion forum, but as recently as Autumn 2023, the DF Developer Team states:

There's no API or framework function that would let us say "constrain
this app that's forcing full screen to these co-ordinates." It's
something we've worked on intermittently to try and get something
working reliably with no luck.

What works

Your Display has a Picture-in-picture and picture-by-picture mode. So, you can hook up both a DP and a HDMI cable from your PC, and Windows will recognize two distinct monitors. Caveat: the display will be limited to 120Hz and SDR. This has been reported to work, but I can't test it.

Use Windowed Borderless Gaming, if needed in combination with DisplayFusion, PowerToys or  MaxTo virtual screen splitter (MaxTo is reported to work "best" in the above linked Reddit thread).



I'm trying to do use maxto and borderless gaming right now, but when I do, it still uses the fullscreen instead of the regions i set
